# Service worker sync event is not getting fired again after failure in first time

Tags: service-worker

This is my code of sync event. Am I doing wrong by handling the promise of sync() method? Should not I handle promise which is inside event.waitUntil() method?

```
`self.addEventListener('sync', function(event) {
    if (event.tag == "esssync") {    
      event.waitUntil(sync()
      .then(function(data){     
        console.log(data);
        try{
          if (Notification.permission === 'granted'){
            self.registration.showNotification("Sync success" + data);
          }else{
            console.log("Sync success");
          }
        }catch(err){
          console.log("Sync success");
        }
      })
      .catch(function(err){
          console.log("Could not sync, scheduled for the next time");
      }));
    }
});`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jake Archibald's [guide to Background Sync](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/12/background-sync) is a great source of information; it contains the following:

> [The promise passed to `event.waitUntil` indicates]
>   the success/failure of whatever it’s trying to do. If it
>   fulfills, the sync is complete. If it fails, another sync will be
>   scheduled to retry.

You're passing in a promise that always fulfills, because you have a `.catch()` function at the end of it, and you don't throw an error or return a rejected promise from within that `.catch()`. You just have a single `console.log()` statement.

The `.catch()` function is analogous to the `catch` block in traditional `try {} / catch {}` exception handling. You need to re-throw the original error from inside your `catch {}` block if you want it to propagate up the call stack, and the same thing applies with `.catch()` if you want the error to cause the promise to reject.

```
event.waitUntil(
  sync()
    .then(data => /* do something with data */)
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('Could not sync; scheduled for the next time', error);
      throw error; // Alternatively, `return Promise.reject(error);`
    }))
);
```

You can also just leave out the `.catch()` entirely, and rely on the fact that passing in the rejected promise to `event.waitUntil()` should log something in the JavaScript console by default.

Comment: Thank you very much, will try that and revert.

Comment: It worked absolutely fine. Apology for late respond.